# Getting http 403 error when accessing website from remote client

Tags: iis-7, windows-authentication, http-status-code-403

I have created an asp.net website that is to be accessed from client browsers running on the same domain.

I've hosted the site on IIS 7.5

I have disabled Anonymous Authentication and Enabled Windows Authentication from the Features View under the IIS section.

I have added the following in the web.config for the site:

```
<authorization>
  <allow users="group\BizTalk Application Users" />
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

I am able to open the website from a browser when running on the server that is hosting the site. However, if I then logon to a different server in the same domain, using the same credentials, when I try to browse to the site I get an http 403 error.

After getting no joy with the above I tried disabling all security to the site. I disabled Windows Authentication and enabled anonymous authentication but still I get the same error. I checked the IIS log on the server and can see that the sub code for the 403 is 18.

I've run fiddler on the client and see the following request / response:

**Request**

```
GET http://tst-bts01/Vasanta.Int.SEOPSupportApp/Orders.aspx HTTP/1.1
Accept: image/jpeg, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-application,       application/xaml+xml, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-  powerpoint, application/msword, */*
Accept-Language: en-GB
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0;   SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: tst-bts01
```

**Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 29 Jan 2013 10:24:34 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

I've tried changing the app pool that hosts the site. I've tried disabling the call the corporate proxy (isa server), running out of ideas now.

Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong?

Thanks, Rob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was a 403.18. Seems that this was caused by the fact that I'd setup custom error messages for authorization failures.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the webserver logs; by default, these are stored in `%SYSTEMDIR%\LogFiles\`.

The line corresponding to the above request includes a *substatus error code* in addition to the 403 status; those codes are [**explained in detail on the Microsoft support website.**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943891/en-us)

Answer (score 0):

Following on from your reply "Seems that this was caused by the fact that I'd setup custom error messages for authorization failures." I wanted to share something similar. I was working on a deployment of a VB.Net ASP webforms app that was returning 403 error. It worked fine in Classic Pipeline mode but not Integrated, which the Developer required. When I turned Custom Errors off in IIS (Detailed Errors inside of "Error Pages" on the Application Menu) it fixed the issue, however of course this wasn't a long term fix, so I had to investigate further...

I had already tried insuring .Net Framework version were installed, ran `aspnet_regiis`, checked the Application Pool has access to the folder etc.

It turned out that the Developer had set an error code of 403 inside the code, something like as below:

```vb
If (Not Me.Inst.User.IsLoggedIn) Then
    Me._PageName = "You must be logged in"
    ' Some other Code Here
Else
    Me._PageName = "Access Denied"
    ' Some other Code Here
End If
Me.Page.Response.StatusCode = 403
```

So regardless of whether the user is just not logged in, or their access is denied, a 403 status code is being applied to the response.

My understanding is that in classic mode this is not a huge problem because ASP.Net does not have full control of all the request and responses, but in integrated mode it does. So, when “Custom Errors” are turned on, the server sees a 403 and redirects to a custom page, which by default is the 403 page we’ve been seeing. When detailed error display is on instead, it is looking for runtime Exceptions to display, and since none occur, it doesn’t interfere.

So the simple solution was to take out the last line of the code block, or possibly put it inside the Else block.

Answer (score -1):

The possible solution is to install “ASP.NET v4.0” as Application Pool on IIS.

ASP.NET v4.0
ASP.NET v4.0 Classic

[Solution here](http://csharpcode.org/iis-fixed-403-forbidden-access-is-denied/):

> To install open command prompt (Press Windows + R and type cmd and
>   press ENTER).
>
> Type cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ and press
>   ENTER.
>
> Type aspnet_regiis.exe -ir and press ENTER again.
>
> This will installing .NET’s framework into IIS for you.
>
> After successful install Close the command prompt.
>
> Now, you need to modify the Application Pool for your site.
>
> Expand out your Sites node and locate the site you want to modify
>   (select it).
>
> To the right you’ll notice “Basic Settings…” just below the Edit Site
>   text. Click this, and a new window should appear.
>
> Select the .NET 4 Application pool using the “Select…” button and
>   click OK. Restart the site.